# xv6 KERNBASE limitation of process memory

Tags: unix, process, kernel, xv6

There is a question in the xv6 book which bothers me for a long time, and I wondered if anyone would like to clarify on this

> KERNBASE limits the amount of memory a single process can use, which might be
>   irritating on a machine with a full 4 GB of RAM. Would raising KERNBASE allow a
>   process to use more memory?

In my opinion the answer to this question is no, since the whole mechanism around xv6 is designed to work with `KERNBASE` on a specific address space.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is an issue here.

All physical addresses which are supposed to be used are mapped to virtual addresses
0x80000000 and up.

So, if you move KERNBASE upawards, the OS can use less physical memory.

Answer (score 3):

I've been thinking about this as well. Here are my conclusions—though I can't really vouch for them. It's mostly deductive.

The first thing is that your proposed explanation is technically wrong. xv6 *can* work with both higher *and lower* `KERNBASE` values. You can test this by changing `KERNBASE` to, say, `0x90000000` and then changing the relevant value in `kernel.ld` (the linker script which puts things in expected addresses).

The real issue here, as far as I've been able to gather, is that xv6 doesn't do any paging to disk. Now, remember that in xv6 addresses `0x80000000` (`KERNBASE`) and up map linearly to `0x00000000..0xffffffff`. This means that any byte of memory you allocate in the whole system maps to 2 different physical addresses in 32-bit space. Since xv6 does no paging to disk, this means that if it allocates memory for the user process (using the `sbrk()` system call, used by `malloc()` in userspace), then it keeps it around in memory the whole time. So again, since we have 2 "copies", or more precisely 2 mappings to the same address, we can't ever actually use more than half the memory available in 32-bit address space.

Now, recall that `KERNBASE` is defined as `0x80000000`, which is exactly that: half of the available memory. So no, raising `KERNBASE` under these conditions can't give us more userspace memory.

Comment: you will have to fix the v2p and p2v functions if you change KERNBASE

Comment: @Morass Fix how? They use the macro in their definition.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. KERNBASE was chosen somewhat arbitrarily if I understand it correctly. Yes it maps the addresses starting from KERNBASE to lower addresses, but the only point of it is so that the kernel can live in physical memory even if there's no available memory at those high addresses. Now, assume we have full 4 Gbs. Since the kernel does not occupy 2Gbs, KERNBASE can be safely moved up to the point of (4Gb - sizeof(kernel)), which should leave the rest of available physical memory for processes.

Answer (score 0):

Necrobumping here, but I will post my answer due to my recent struggles with this topic :D

IMO technically answer is no, if you rise KERNBASE like it was said here the kernel will have less memory mapped for processes and their allocations.  If you lower KERNBASE, you will shrink process address space, so half of the address space is a sweet spot in the case of xv6.

That being said, I struggled with this on my own because without context this answer is kind of saying 'it's just that way' for a person trying to wrap their head around OSes inner workings.

This design is derived from the following facts:

- xv6 is a 32-bit system - so address space (it's important - address
  space - not memory) is up to 4 gigs
- a processor cannot use physical
  addresses if you ask it to load contents of  some memory to register,
  the address you gave will be translated by MMU (hardware) it's just
  built that way
- a kernel is mapped into each process
  address space to avoid changing the page table (thus invalidating
  TLB cache) when a process does syscall (switch to kernel mode) ofc
  there are other reasons but this one seems most relevant imo
- like
  yam-marcovic said - there is no swapping memory to disk in xv6 so in
  a sense xv6 use paging but does not have virtual memory. I.e 32 bit
  Linux uses 3/1 split because it can left  more address space for the
  processes - kernel  can swap out memory to disk, so it doesn't have
  to keep all the stuff in physical memory

Theoretically, you will hit the same problem in the case of 64-bit system if physical memory amounts become equal to or greater than 64-bit address space can address. Practically, no one cares because it's huge compared to a 32-bit one.

What I am trying to say here is that this design and its limitations come from the conjunction of software design on top of how hardware works.

I still can't answer to myself if mapping kernel to higher virtual addresses it's just for the convenience of some type or if there is any hard technical reason.